# Accidentally asked a question from my company account, deleted it and trying to post it from my personal account but says it's a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I have been trying to post my question with my personal account rather than the company's Stack Overflow Teams account after deleting it, but it says this question is a duplicate of a deleted one. Even if when I try to open the link again it says the page is not found.

[image]

Comment: Probably caching. Try waiting an hour or so?

Comment: See also [It's not working! Should I blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/). Hint: yes.