# Invalidate Reopen Votes review queue items created after reopening and immediately closing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen

I just reopened [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370886/accidentally-asked-a-question-from-my-company-account-deleted-it-and-trying-to) and immediately (within a few seconds) closed it as a duplicate. However, it seems the reopen 'vote' put it into the Reopen Votes review queue (where I encountered it [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/79729) and left it closed). This seems an unintended by-product of immediately creating review items after certain actions<sup>*</sup> (there used to be a delay of 5-15 minutes; it seemed like the system was smart enough to see that the reopener closed the question themselves and review was not necessary). Perhaps creating the review queue item can't be avoided, but at least it should be invalidated after I reclose the question. This probably also applies to gold-tag-badge holders reopening ['old style' duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181915/295232) and close them to make them look like contemporary duplicates.

[image]

<sup>*</sup><sub>I'm quite certain this is a recent change and I have seen it announced somewhere, but I'm failing to find a reference. It's quite apparent in the new First Questions and First Answers queues, which on many sites contain fresh posts only seconds old.</sub>

Comment: [Here's a recent case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411588) where this exact thing happened on SO, and was noticed and posted to meta. It's a weird corner case that doesn't appear to have been planned for.

Comment: If the vote reopen reopens the question, the review task shouldn't be created. I would review the close vote code too just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the chance to look into this!

Here's what was happening:

When the user votes to reopen a post, if it opens the post outright, it still gets added to the queue - it just gets invalidated 5 minutes or so after through the Sync() method.

In this particular scenario, the `Sync()` check was failing (er, rather, passing?) because the post was already closed by the time it checked, so `Sync()` thought that the post should indeed still be in the queue.

I'd thought originally that the method `AddToReopenQueue` - which was attached to the `AddFlagToPost` event - would successfully identify if a post was opened based on the vote FIRST, so the `Post.IsClosed` check would fail and it wouldn't get added. ...I was wrong.

To fix it, we moved the `AddToReopenQueue` method call to inside the `AddFlagForReopen` method, so that we only try to add to the queue if the flag doesn't reopen the post. This should fix both this scenario, and also fix the instances in which a post gets added to the queue and then invalidated right away.

Thanks for reporting, the fix is in review right now and should be shipped within the next few days.